# Limiting messages in Centos log file

Tags: linux, centos, logging, syslog, webmin

I have a Centos 6.4 server.  I wish to view httpd and PHP errors in `/var/log/messages`.  The log shows a bunch of kernel messages which I don't want to view.

How can I either configure syslog to not log these messages, or configure webmin to not show them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move your httpd and php logs elsewhere, as many applications write to syslog by default, and it will take some time to prune each one of them out of syslog.

By default httpd on centos writes logs in /var/log/httpd. You can change this behaviour by changing the symlink in /etc/httpd/logs

Comment: As further explanation you may also comment kern facility to prevent those messages from appearing in log-files, BUT it's not a good a idea. Create separate file for your service using daemon.ServiceName* -/var/log/ServiceName.log